# Append list into a single pandas data frame cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to append a list of results into a single pandas data frame cell, but using the .append method results in a column with a row for each of the elements of the list.

For example if I use the following:

```
parameters = [1, 3, 4, 5]
X = pd.DataFrame()
X = X.append(parameters)
X
```

I get:

```
0   1

1   3

2   4

3   5
```

Where the first column is the index.

And what I'd like to get the 4 elements into a single cell, so something like this:

```
0 1 3 4 5
```

Where the "0" is the index and "1 3 4 5" are in a single cell.

I've tried converting the list into a string but then I can't append that into the data frame, I've also tried looping but then I get the same result.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your DataFrame with a placeholder for your list, then assign via `loc`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=['A'])
df      
     A
0  NaN

df.loc[0, 'A'] = parameters
df
            A
0  [1, 3, 4, 5]
```